The emulator process has been terminated
I am facing the folllowing issues in Latest Android Studio (Android Studio Koala| 2024.1.1 patch 2), I try to run emulator, but it showing the below error,
As I tried many ways,

Checking the memory
Enable HAMX, Hyper -V and Windows Hypervisor Platform also,
I also attached the screen shot.


2024-08-15 12:07:34,120 [ 242783]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_7a_API_34 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2024-08-15 12:07:34,391 [ 243054]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - [2800:8100:20240815,120734.391:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\1f49e12e-e6d1-4cd2-941d-5b2331c5c9c2: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-15 12:07:34,391 [ 243054]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 12756
2024-08-15 12:07:34,391 [ 243054]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A)
2024-08-15 12:07:34,391 [ 243054]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64
2024-08-15 12:07:34,670 [ 243333]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - [16668:10628:20240815,120734.670:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\1f49e12e-e6d1-4cd2-941d-5b2331c5c9c2: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-15 12:07:34,715 [ 243378]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: b0b5:4f18:7101:0:a0a8:4f18:7101:0 (2x)
2024-08-15 12:07:34,715 [ 243378]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\IBM5788.android\avd\Pixel_7a_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-08-15 12:07:36,280 [ 244943]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-15 12:07:36,281 [ 244944]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-15 12:07:41,789 [ 250452]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - API level 34 requires OpenGL ES 3.0+, attempting to turn on OpenGL ES 3.0/3.1
2024-08-15 12:07:41,789 [ 250452]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
2024-08-15 12:07:41,789 [ 250452]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2024-08-15 12:07:41,804 [ 250467]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0
2024-08-15 12:07:41,804 [ 250467]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - OpenGL Core Profile not supported.
2024-08-15 12:07:41,986 [ 250649]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - [16668:10628:20240815,120741.986:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\797519f5-6aa5-48e6-adca-5924d5d7c08b: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-15 12:07:42,001 [ 250664]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - [16668:10628:20240815,120741.986:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\797519f5-6aa5-48e6-adca-5924d5d7c08b: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-15 12:07:42,001 [ 250664]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - [16668:10628:20240815,120741.986:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
2024-08-15 12:07:42,408 [ 251071]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - [16668:10628:20240815,120742.408:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\797519f5-6aa5-48e6-adca-5924d5d7c08b: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-15 12:07:42,418 [ 251081]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-08-15 12:07:42,418 [ 251081]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
2024-08-15 12:07:42,478 [ 251141]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7a_API_34 has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7a_API_34 has terminated.
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-08-15 12:08:34,600 [ 303263]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.analytics.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80'
2024-08-15 12:09:21,312 [ 349975]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.ActionStub - ActionGroup should be registered using  tag: id="Android.CreateResourcesActionGroup" class="org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateResourceFileActionGroup"

1. Check GPU Compatibility
The logs indicate a potential issue with OpenGL ES 3.0 support and your GPU drivers. Make sure your GPU drivers are up-to-date.
You might also want to try switching the emulator to use software rendering. You can do this by modifying the emulator settings:
Go to AVD Manager > Select your AVD > Click on Edit (pencil icon) > Show Advanced Settings.
Under Emulated Performance, change Graphics to Software - GLES 2.0.
2. Clear Emulator Cache
Sometimes, corrupt cache files can cause the emulator to crash. Try clearing the emulator cache:
Open the AVD Manager.
Click on the dropdown arrow next to your AVD and select Wipe Data.
Restart the emulator to see if this resolves the issue.
Check for Disk Space and Permissions
Ensure that there is enough disk space on your machine, especially in the directories where the Android SDK and AVDs are stored.
Also, check that your user has sufficient permissions to read/write in the directories mentioned in the error logs (C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and C:\Users\IBM5788\AppData\Local\Temp).
4. Recreate the AVD
If the problem persists, try deleting and recreating the AVD:
Go to AVD Manager.
Delete the problematic AVD.
Create a new AVD with the same or different device settings.
5. Check for Emulator Updates
Ensure that your Android Emulator is up to date. Go to the SDK Manager and update the Emulator and related tools to the latest version.
6. Check Windows Features
Since you mentioned enabling Hyper-V, ensure that the following features are enabled in Windows:

Windows Hypervisor Platform

Virtual Machine Platform

Hyper-V


You can enable these by searching for "Windows Features" and ensuring the relevant checkboxes are selected.
7. Try Disabling Hyper-V (if necessary)
Sometimes, Hyper-V can conflict with Android Emulator. So you can try disabling Hyper-V and then run the emulator again.
8. Run as Administrator
Try running Android Studio as an administrator so it has the necessary permissions to access all files and hardware resources.
9. Check for Missing Files
The log mentions missing files in the Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db directory. You might want to manually clear the Temp directory and let the emulator regenerate any necessary files.

I faced the same issue after upgrading to koala feature drop. i can't start all AVDs using Device Manager.
i'm using win 11 pro. downgrading to jellyfish does not resolve.
i got error message "vcruntime140.dll was not found" when i run the emulator on the command prompt.
in my case, folder "c:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator" has this module.
after changing the directory to emulator on the command prompt, emulator.exe with parms works fine.
To bypass this problem:
i just copied vcruntime140.dll from "c:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator" to "c:\windows\system32".
but it still fails with other modules. total 5 modules are required to run the emulator.
vcruntime140.dll
vcruntime140_1.dll
msvcp140.dll
msvcp140_1.dll
msvcp140_2.dll
above modules may be installed by "Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable".
after copying above modules, Device Manager can start AVD.

Installing AMD Radeon™ Series Graphics and Ryzen™ Chipsets drivers made my emulator not crash on start up.

Intel HAXM is deprecated.
This solved the problem for me:
Uninstall Intel HAXM and install the Android Emulator hypervisor driver.
See documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#haxm-uninstall

After trying several alternatives, I managed to solve my problem just by updating the video card driver, after that the driver updated the dll "vulkan-1.dll" which is located in "C:\Windows\System32" and the emulator finally returned to function correctly.
Remembering that I use an Intel processor and NVIDIA graphics card.

I have got exactly the same issue and have managed to solve it by installing Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable
